# как можно поменять баннер сервера через бота дискорд

Tags: python, discord

Пытался найти в документации - ничего не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: а вы уверены, что это вообще возможно?

Comment: Я не уверен, но мне сказали, что это возможно

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov У программистов все возможно. Когда есть гугл ;) [banner-changer](https://github.com/NotNorom/banner-changer) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про это: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html#discord.Guild.edit

Примерный код команды на изменение баннера будет выглядеть вот так:

```py
import os
    
    
@commands.command()
async def change_banner(self, ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    file = await ctx.message.attachments[0].save(fp=ctx.message.attachments[0].filename)  # Скачиваем первое изображение, указанное в сообщении вызова команды.
    with open(file, 'rb') as image:
        await ctx.guild.edit(banner=image.read())  # При помощи метода read() читаем изображение, и ставим его как баннер на сервере

    os.remove(file)  # Удаляем скачанное изображение
```

P.S. данная команда адаптирована под [коги](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cogs#discord.ext.commands.Bot.cogs)

Comment: Спасибо, AlekseyZz, очень помогли)

Comment: @ElusivityOwner Я рад, что помог)